# JFrame created with netbeans looks ok in design window but is messed up when I run it

Tags: java, swing, layout, netbeans, layout-manager

I've been designing an application using netbeans designer mode. It has been going pretty good, but there is a problem: The layout looks great when I am designing, but when I run the program, it looks all messed up, here you can compare between them.

As you can see, it looks fine and well aligned in the designer window:

[image: design view]

But, when I run the program, the alignment gets all messed

[image: run]

Every label and jTextField is inside a little individual panel, to make some things easier.

I would like to know how I can prevent this from happening, thank you for your time.

Comment: What specifically are you concerned about being "messed up?"  They look the same to me except for a couple of minor width differences, probably due to fonts and bad alignment constraints.  Your extra panels are likely preventing the normal alignment mechanism in Matisse from working.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer, don't use the "free form layout", it gets screwy real quickly.

Use instead something like `GridBagLayout`.

Layout each separate group it's own pane and drag them into the master pane.

Comment: Hey, thank you, that worked perfectly. What does "Grid Bag Layout" exactly mean and how is it different to the Default "Free Design"?

Comment: `GridBagLayout` is another layout manager (like `FreeForm`) but, IMHO is better at achieving it's results. The `FreeForm` layout manager is good, but I keep having problems with it screwing up my layouts. You might finding reading through [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) helpful